# Error in Send email in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

When users login to site facing this error

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Authentication required

Help me 
i did not write anything for SMTP in Web.Config

```
// Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("elahi2mahdi@yahoo.com", "Hello");
        mail.To.Add(message.Destination);
        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        // attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/textfile.txt");
        // mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpServer.Port =587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("elahi2mahdi@yahoo.com", "password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
       SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        // SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        return SmtpServer.SendMailAsync(mail);
```

Comment: Wait. Why are you mixing `SmtpClient` and `SmtpServer`? You just need `SmtpClient`. You're half using one object and half using another.

Comment: If your using yahoo's client you need to provide them with a valid user/password.

Comment: what to write ?

Comment: @itsme86 it is a very badly named variable but they are only using an SmtpClient. Its instance is held in `SmtpServer`. ....

Comment: @rene Oh, you're right.

Comment: `SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` set that to false if you are providing a network credential (which you are, 2 lines up)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you have unnecessarily over complicated your solution of making a simple smtp request to yahoo. There is no need for SMTP Server at all. Have a look at the following article: [Send Email from Yahoo](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520998/Send-Email-from-Yahoo-GMail-Hotmail-Csharp)

Essentially (extracted from the article) this is what you should do (credit goes to original poster):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

string smtpAddress = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
int portNumber = 587;
bool enableSSL = true;

string emailFrom = "email@yahoo.com";
string password = "abcdefg";
string emailTo = "someone@domain.com";
string subject = "Hello";
string body = "Hello, I'm just writing this to say Hi!";

using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
    mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
    mail.To.Add(emailTo);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    // Can set to false, if you are sending pure text.

    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeFile.txt"));
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeZip.zip"));

    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
    {
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
        smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show error exists for these code 
   mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeFile.txt"));
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeZip.zip"));

Comment: help me for this problem

Comment: Remove those 2 statements. They are basically for adding attachements to your email and if you don't have any attachments, you don't need them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Show error A task was canceled for this code

```
                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
```

Code

```
string smtpAddress = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        int portNumber = 587;
        bool enableSSL = true;

        string emailFrom = "elahi2mahdi@yahoo.com";
        string password = "password";
        string emailTo =message.Destination;
        string subject = message.Subject;
        string body = message.Body;

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
            mail.To.Add(emailTo);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            // Can set to false, if you are sending pure text.

            //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeFile.txt"));
            //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeZip.zip"));

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
               return smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
            }
        }
```